# How to create a hierarchy within filters in filter bar

Tags: filter, data, surveys, design-process, flow

Currently, I create a survey builder where the user is able to preview all pre-defined questions within the database and based on this user chooses what type of survey would like to create. Based on the research this functionality is really important to the user to help him understand what type of survey wants to create and what questions wants to include.

Therefore, while entering the survey builder all questions should be visible (based on user research + project manager requirement). BUT to start creating a survey user has to choose the survey type (Questions within survey types can't be mixed up therefore it's crucial to fill in this information before survey creation).

I have created a filter bar where the survey type dropdown is equal to other filters.
Additionally, I added a communicate to the user in the bar to highlight that the survey type has to be chosen.

However, this is not the best UX. I'm struggling a lot with it and would love to hear your input on how to structure data with mentioned above dependencies...

Maybe I should highlight the Survey type filter more? I can't though force user to choose the survey type before entering the survey because than he won't see all the questions...

Here is initial prototype:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### If the survey type has to be selected first, separate the action of choosing a survey from viewing the questions.

Since the survey builds in the right pane, you could place a control of some sort, right where it will start being created:

[image]

This way you have an opportunity to educate them on survey types, and prevent a mistaken choice. So much of UX is the *error prevention business*,(followed by the *error recovery business*).

You've got a nice drag and drop question list, so putting the survey type in the drop area makes it clear they have to choose first. Any attempt to drag a question in can give them a prompt to choose a survey type.

If you make this clear enough, you may not even need the high color, high profile instruction bar. You also won't need an action in the bar, since the only action to begin is to select an option.

**Once selected:**

At this point, the filter bar can appear, and they can then filter the remaining questions scoped by the choice of survey.

**Option 2: have the filters there from the beginning, but once a survey has been chosen, disable or remove the 'survey type' filter .**

This option allows you to filter the question pane on the left, which would allow the user to see only questions from a specific survey type before choosing. Then it can be removed (or disabled) once a specific survey is being built.

It seems what's confusing is mixing the action of selecting a path vs the question set available once that path has been chosen.

By being explicit about the action to take first allows the user to both see all questions (unfiltered), while viewing the available actions to take (the survey types).

Comment: Thank you very much this is a brilliantly simple and clear solution with error prevention! Additionally, perfectly fills the empty space to the right. I'm on my holiday now. I start to work on it next week again and I come back to you :)

Comment: Dear Mike, after further reconsideration I decided to move on with your suggestion based on arguments mentioned above. thank you very much for help.